# JavaScript get nested property without breaking

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I  am receiving a deeply nested object. I don't know which properties will be present. If I want to get the image, I can't just do this

```
data.opposite.info.logo.images.s.resized_urls.s,
```

Imagine this comes from a system where user can leave the logo empty, then my code will break. Do I need to check the existence of properties like this?

```
if(data.opposite){

   if(data.opposite.info)

     if(data.opposite.info.images)

//...etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript's `try { ... } catch(e) { ... }` block.

```
try { 
  url = data.opposite.info.logo.images.s.resized_urls.s; } 
catch(e) { 
  url =  '' 
}
```

Also [loadash.js](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) has a get method that can help you with this

```
var url = _.get(data, 'opposite.info.logo.images.s.resized_urls.s', '');
```

this will traverse deep into the object if the path exists and return the 's'. If it is not there, it returns the last argument which is '' in this case.

Comment: use lodash is not a bad choice as it's only one line. but I don't think you need `''` in the first param of _.get.

Comment: Thanks @JessieAnderson. Corrected it

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to get value by scan object: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sharekno/9vLp02hd/)

```
function getObjByProperty(obj, propertyName) {
  if (obj instanceof Object) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
        return obj[propertyName];
    }
    for (var val in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(val)) {
            var result = getObjByProperty(obj[val], propertyName);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
   } else {
    return null;
  }
 }

 var images = getObjByProperty(data, 'images');
 if (images) {      
  console.log(images);
 }
```